# jQuery "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, that are for showing and hiding elements by class:

```
if (typeof showClass != 'function') {
    function showClass(trClass, buttonId, hideMessage, showMessage) {
        var button = '#' + buttonId;
        var value = hideMessage;
        $(button).attr("value", value);
        $(button).attr("onclick", "hideClass('" + trClass + "', '" + buttonId + "', '" + showMessage + "', '" + hideMessage + ");");
        var classToShow = '.' + trClass;
        $(classToShow).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
}

if (typeof hideClass != 'function') {
    function hideClass(trClass, buttonId, showMessage, hideMessage) {
        var button = '#' + buttonId;
        var value = showMessage;
        $(button).attr("value", value);
        $(button).attr("onclick", "showClass('" + trClass + "', '" + buttonId + "', '" + hideMessage + "', '" + showMessage + ");");
        var classToHide = '.' + trClass;
        $(classToHide).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

showClass works as excepted, but hideClass causes error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in Chrome. With FireFox I don't get any errors, but the function doesn't work with either of the browsers. I tried with different editors to find some illegal characters etc., but no luck. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: You've got jQuery - use `.on('click', ...)` to register a proper event handler instead of setting the `onclick` HTML attribute!

Comment: don't tell me ... you trying to reCreate `toggle()` function.  please google jquery.toggle() and check it out

Comment: @bipen don't forget that `toggle(fn1, fn2)` is now deprecated

Comment: @Alnitak no need of `toggle(fn1,fn2)`..simple toggle will work in think...`$('#'.buttonId).click(function(){ $('.trClass').toggle() })` ...:) :)

Comment: @bipen that won't handle toggling the label on the button

Comment: yaaa.. :).. correct.. i was wondring why is that value there... damn!!! i need a coffe now.. :)..

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently trying to set up a toggling button, but it's the most convoluted mess of jQuery and inline event handlers I've ever seen.

Try this:

```
function setupToggle(trigger, target, hideMessage, showMessage) {
    var state = false;      // true means button says "show", target is hidden
    var $el = $(trigger);

    function update() {
        $el.attr('value', state ? showMessage : hideMessage);
        $(target).css('visibility', state ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
    }

    update();  // set initial state

    $el.on('click', function() {
        state = !state;   // on click, flick state and refresh
        update();
    });
}
```

usage:

```
setupToggle('#mybutton', '.mytr', 'Hide it', 'Show it');
```

The code above may require minor tweaks depending on whether the default state is "hidden" or "shown".

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I'm just a "simple" backend developer / system architect, so javascript is not my thing :).